# Can't redirect React routes on github pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

I have a react page that uses react-router.

When I run the app locally, I am able to redirect the default path to a specific component.  (In my particular case, the '/' redirects to the '/shop' component.)

```
<Route exact path="/" >
    <Redirect to="/store" />
 </Route>
```

However, when I deploy the app to GitHub pages, the default path doesn't redirect to the shop component.

https://vezinaca.github.io/redux-shopping-cart

I've tried adding 'shop' to the "homepage": "http://vezinaca.github.io/redux-shopping-cart/", line of my package.json file but this did not work.